# Building and installing MongoDB C++ driver in OS X

Tags: c++, xcode, mongodb

I have downloaded the latest version of MongoDB C++ driver for my os x from http://dl.mongodb.org/dl/cxx-driver. Then I extracted using tar xvf command in os x terminal. After that I run scons to build the driver. It build successfully by giving following messages

```
-- some messages --
ranlib build/libmongoclient.a
ranlib: file: build/libmongoclient.a(backtrace.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: build/libmongoclient.a(posix_fadvise.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: build/libmongoclient.a(ssl_manager.o) has no symbols
Install file: "build/libmongoclient.a" as "libmongoclient.a"
scons: done building targets.
```

So, then I run the command "scons install" to install the library into my machine.

```
--some messages --
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `install' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
```

But when I check into the /usr/local directory for the libmongoclient libs, It's not there. 
But inside my extracted mongoDB driver folder, there is a file with the name of "libmongoclient.a". But there is no file with the extension of ".dylib". Then How do I use mongoDB Xcode & gcc C++ ?
Somebody help me to link with "libmongoclient" library from Xcode.

Comment: Did you not have to build the C driver first?  Here's what I'm seeing on github's build instructions:  "The C++ driver uses libbson and the MongoDB C driver internally. The C driver will install libbson if it isn't already present."  This link was directed from mongodb-dot-org's C++ MongoDB Driver page (https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/cpp/client/#compile-the-driver).  Reason I ask:  I'm stuck on the C installation on Cygwin having to do with WINSOCK stuff.  Won't go into detail and evolve into a separate question, but don't want to create anew because there are duplicates already.

Comment: You mean, C driver or C++ driver? Both are slightly different. right?

Comment: How do you interpret my quote, above? I interpreted it as I need to install the C driver because the C++ driver uses it internally. Also, I don't have libbson, so I need the C driver build to create that too.

Comment: Yes. In github page, it's there. But I didn't build the C driver. I built the C++ driver from its source directly because source is self contained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a while to get this working.
Hopefully you can get yours working from the following steps:

**Create a new C++ project in Xcode**

I copied the code from `<mongo_driver_install>/src/mongo/client/examples/tutorial.cpp` as a test

**In Build Settings/Search Paths:**

[image: screen shot of search paths]

Add the following to your `Header Search Paths`:

```
/path/to/mongo-cxx-driver-nightly/src
```

and your equivalent path for the boost library header files (the folder should contain a `boost` folder):

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/include
```

Add the following to your `Library Search Paths`:

```
/usr/local/lib (in my case holds all of the boost libraries)
/path/to/mongo-cxx-driver-nightly
```

**Link Binaries**

In the `Build Phases/Link Binary with Libraries` settings:

[image: Screen shot of build phases]

Add the following binaries:

```
/path/to/mongo-cxx-driver-nightly/libmongoclient.a
/usr/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.dylib
```

Comment: I also needed to add `/usr/local/lib/libboost_regex-mt.dylib`