# Xcode MongoDB Boost import <angled>

Tags: c++, xcode, mongodb, boost

I created a C++ project in Xcode 6.3.2 (Mac Yosemite 10.10.3).
I installed Boost with (brew install boost) and MongoDB (following [this guide](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Download-And-Compile-The-Legacy-Driver)).

I have setted LibrarySearchPath and UserHeaderSearchPath following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008272/building-and-installing-mongodb-c-driver-in-os-x).

Now when I try to launch the application I have a lot of error like this:

```
'boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
```

In all file of boost and mongo, the include path is with angled include.

Xcode seems see the boost library like relative to the project and not to the system.

There's a way to tell Xcode that boost is a system library and not a relative project library?

Answer (score 2):

After a few hours I resolved this stupid problem. It's not `User Header Search Path`, but `Header Search Path`. :)